# GooglePlacePicker doesn’t install via cocoa pods

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoa, google-places

I've tried to install GooglePlacePicker several times through Cocoapods, but I always get this error

```
[!] Error installing GooglePlacePicker
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/tk/yn2rtpyx055g343t53hmqpqc0000gn/T/d20170925-37639-2bym7v/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/2239f9d09050c05e/GooglePlacePicker-2.4.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:40 --:--:--     0
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
```

I also tried to install it manually, but this also did not work for me, since browsers (Safari, Chrome) do not download the archive by reference. When I removed the GooglePlacePicker from the Podfile, the pods were installed well. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the APN settings restart from my modem, then tried to install pods again and it works for me.